# Revoke access facebook ngCordova

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i currently using the ionic-framework and ngCordova for a mobile app.
I'm using ngCordova's Oauth $cordovaOauth http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Oauth for facebook log in.

this is the following code

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("CLIENT_ID_HERE", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        // results
    }, function(error) {
        // error
    });
}
```

my problem is that if the user decides not to share his email, i need to ask him again by revoking the access. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Facebook documentation you need to add `auth_type=rerequest` to the Oauth call.

See the documentation on this here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

Currently ngCordova only supports Facebook sign in on its most basic level so the library source would need to be edited to support this change:

https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/blob/master/ng-cordova-oauth.js#L198

I suggest you add a ticket if you don't want this feature yourself:

https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues

Regards,